# JSON parsing global variable Swift 4

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode, parsing

I just started coding in Swift 4 and need help parsing a JSON for a quiz app. I managed to parse the JSON, but the variable "r" which contains the array is localized within the function. I am trying to make it a global variable but had no luck. I'm using swiftyJSON and Alamofire, but don't mind switching methods if new method is properly explained. Example/functional code would be great if possible. Thank You

```
//struct declaration 
    struct Result : Decodable{
    let question : String?
    let correct_answer : Bool?
}

//var declaration inside class 
        var myResults = [Result]()


//networking and parsing 
    func getQuestionNew(){
        // this is the main screwed up function
        let parameters: Parameters = ["amount": 15, "type":"boolean"]
        Alamofire.request("https://opentdb.com/api.php", method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

            print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
            print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
            print("Result: \(response.result)")



            if((response.result.value) != nil) {
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
                //print(swiftyJsonVar["results"])
                let results = swiftyJsonVar["results"].arrayValue

                results.forEach({ (item) in
                    //print("Printing Item \(item["question"].stringValue)")
                    print("Printing Item \(item)")

                    var r = Result(question: item["question"].stringValue, correct_answer: item["correct_answer"].stringValue == "True" ? true : false)
                    print(r)
                    self.myResults.append(r)

                    //                    print(r)

                })



            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code (except the question why are the members of `Result` optional although they are initialized with non-optional values and `Decodable` is unused). The property `myResults` is populated correctly. But you have to consider that `request` works asynchronously, the data source array is populated later. Either put the code to be executed after receiving the data in the closure or use a completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for variable r declaration

```
var r: Result?
```

Initialise this variable r in ViewDidLoad()

```
self.r = Result()
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, but I am not able to pull a specific value from the array. For example. r.question[2] and the error is"Type 'Result' has no subscript members" //    func printJSONOutsideFunction(){
        print(r![2].question)
    }

Comment: r is not array type, how can you use subscription on object. Use r.question only... I think you have to use myResults[2].question... you can use here